# How to automate my web pages for testing using Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-rc

I am using selenium for my web automated testing. finally i have make simple program to open a browser using selenium. But i am not getting a good document for this. Like watin has. Can anu buddy suggest me a good document where i can see what and how method of selenium do?

Please help me out from this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified if you need help with the Selenium IDE or RC?

Links I have used in the past:

[The official Selenium documentation](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/)

[Selenium Tutorial for Beginner/Tips for Experts](http://jroller.com/selenium/)

[Selenium IDE Tutorial – Part 1](http://www.codediesel.com/php/selenium-ide-tutorial-part-1/) (and Part 2)

[Build A Test of a Rich Internet Application In 30 Minutes Or Less](http://www.pushtotest.com/tutorials/selenium-tutorial-full) (but you need PushToTest)

[Selenium RC : Importing a script from Selenium IDE](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.com/2010/10/selenium-rc-importing-script-from.html)

If you are keen to expand the functionality, you need to research [XPath](http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/tutorials/selenium/selenium_xpath.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2006/05/14/144666.aspx

You can google other resources. [documentation](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a number of tutorials on how to use Selenium on my [site](http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/selenium_training.htm)